# How to add link to a static page in Yii framework in routing rules?

Tags: php, yii

i hav my routing rules as

```
'components'=>array(
    /*'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',            
    ),*/
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(  
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'


        )
```

now i want to hav a img inside my page that links to a static webpage
eg.

```
<a href="www.example.com"><img></a>
```

however this link redirects to

```
 www.example.com/example.com
```

what rule should i add so that only on this link it redirects to the static page

and my sitebase is www.example.com

so any link generated by Yii is always

```
www.example.com/"something"
```

Comment: Has your static site same domain like your Yii installation or is it at a different server/domain?

Comment: it is the same..
my main work is done in www.example.com/index.php
and have a static homepage in www.example.com
that is what i am trying to link to

Comment: So at `www.example.com/index.php` you work with Yii and at `www.example.com` is a static (html) homepage?

Comment: yes ,this is how we do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO it like this using `CHtml`(**Recommended by Everyone**)

```
echo CHtml::link('Yii External Link', "http://www.example.com");
```

OR

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img></a>
```

Comment: I'd recommend first solution with `CHtml::link()`. Better delete my solution with `http://` - it's just a quick win and not the way Yii works.

Comment: @Jurik, Your recommendation is same with mine to

Comment: is this how i should use it?
because it is not working
    <a href="<?php echo CHtml::link('home', 'www.example.com');?>">

Comment: @raviyadav, no need to add extra '<a></a>' see more here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/

Comment: @BeingSunny hi..tried that for simple text and image link still it redirects to 
 www.example.com/example.com

using only the chtml no  <a>

Comment: @raviyadav, Did you try `echo CHtml::link('Yii External Link', "http://www.example.com");`?

Comment: @BeingSunny, yes this created a text link to www.example.com/example.com

Comment: my mistake
.i did forget to put that..it worked
thanks.

Comment: @raviyadav Ok, best of luck